# How to get input box values and the select box values to store it in array and do calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get input box values and select box values to store it each one in array and do some calculation and I couldn't get a result here is my javascript code:-

```js
$(window).on('pageinit', function() {
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Scal").click(function() { 
var x = parseFloat($('[name^="Sc"]').val()) || 0
var y = parseFloat($('[name^="Sgrade"]').val()) || 0
var sum1 = 0;
var sum2 = 0;
for(var i=0; i< x.length; i++) {
    sum1 += x[i]*y[i];
 sum2 += x[i];
}
var sum3 = sum1/sum2
var sum3 = sum3.toFixed(2)
$('#Sres').val(sum3)
  });
  });
});
```

Comment: What exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: @void get all the input values and the select box values, Multiply the array x with array y, sum up all multiplication results, sum up the values of array x and then divide the first sum up with the second sum up and show the result

Comment: @ji-ruh not getting any result at the end. Can't find where is the mistake

Comment: @Binvention here it is http://jsfiddle.net/ees7xubx/1/

Comment: You can loop through all input boxes and store their values. [reference](http://jsfiddle.net/x74h9nfd/). Do same for select and you have all values you need.

Comment: @ji-ruh here it is http://jsfiddle.net/ees7xubx/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over the elements from which you're pulling the values.  Your `parseFloat` approach isn't going to work.

Do something like this to get the sum of all `Sc` values:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var sumSc = 0;

    $("#Scal").click(function () {
        //loop over the matching elements with jQuery each()
        $('[name^="Sc"]').each(function () {
            sumSc += +$(this).val(); //the extra "+" here coerces a Number value
        });
        console.log(sumSc); //this outputs your total in the console
    });
});
```

You can apply that same approach to sum the other elements and do your calculations.

Comment: Thanks for sharing I've understood the concept but what if I wanted to multiply two arrays ?